# MVC2 Drop Down Validation Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I used to get this message when attempting to create drop down controls with required field validation:

The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedNCRType' is of type 'System.Int32' 
but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Somehow I managed to get everything working on my local machine and all looked good. When I published the project however and copied the files to the test server this message again appears whenever the validation on the drop down controls fails. Here is some code snippets:

```
View Model:
[DisplayName("NCR Type:")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> NCRTypeSelectList
{
   get;
   set;
}

[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
public int SelectedNCRType { get; set; }

Controller:
var types = (from x in context.NCRTypes
             where x.Deleted == false
             select new models.NCRType
             {
                 Deleted = x.Deleted,
                 Id = x.Id,
                 Name = x.Name
             }).ToList();
model.NCRTypeSelectList = types.ToSelectList("Id", "Name");

View:
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedNCRType, Model.NCRTypeSelectList, "Select...", new { @class = "form_dropdown_300" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedNCRType, "Required Field")%>

Helper Extension Method:
public static SelectList ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
                         string dataValueField, string dataTextField)
    {
        return new SelectList(collection, dataValueField, dataTextField);
    }
```

If you have any ideas please help... this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by repopulating the drop down controls in the post action method before the line:

return View(model);